# what does #4 line of C++ code does?

Tags: c++

```
class vector{
public:
    vector(int s);
    double& operator[](int i);
    int size();
private:
    double∗ elem;
    int sz;
};
```

## Line 4 : double& operator[](int i);

what this line means in C++ programming principles, I get confused where & is used and [](int i) also quite confusing.

Comment: Programming questions about specific languages are off-topic here, but on-topic on stackoveflow.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Answer (score 6):

It defines the operator `[]` which returns a reference to the double value of the n-th element within the vector.
In this way you can read and write a specific element.
Suppose you have the following:

```
vector my_vector(1000);
```

With the operation `double value = my_vector[3]` you read the value of the 4th element.
With the operation `my_vector[6] = 6.7` you set the value of the 7th element.

Answer (score 3):

```
double& operator[](int i);
```

> what this line means in C++

This line declares an `operator[]` (also known as the "Array subscript operator") implementation, which is commonly used for indexing container types (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::map` and others). Imagine the common `sequence[0]` to access the reference to the first element of a sequence.

> where & is used

In C++, the `&` character appended to a type means "a type that represents a reference to type `Foo`". So for example `int&` is a reference to `int`, and `double&` is a reference to a double.

Now, why would you return references from an `operator[]`? The answer is: because you probably want to write code like this...

```
sequence[0] = 42;
```

...and for this you need `operator[]` implementation to return an lvalue. It just so happens that references are lvalues! Why do you need an lvalue? A simplistic answer is "because left-hand side of an assignment must be an lvalue". I found [this article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/) helpful when learning about lvalues and rvalues.

> and [](int i) also quite confusing.

You parsed this somewhat incorrectly. Look at the declaration this way:

1. `double&`
2. `operator[]`
3. `(int i)`

First part is the return type, second is the name of the function you're implementing, and the third part specifies the parameters your function takes.

Implementations of `operator[]` should take an integer value (`int`, `unsigned`, `size_t` etc.) as a parameter (disclaimer: not sure, couldn't find a "thou shalt" reference for this). This is why your parameter list is `(int)`.

Further reading: go to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators and look for "Array subscript operator".

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to user the [] parameter on the vector object.
it shows you that it receives an int as a parameter (`[i]`), and returns a double, so a line like the following will be valid:

```
double element = vector1[2];
```

or

```
vector1[2] = 4; // since the returned value is a reference
```

where vector1 is an instance of the `vector` class.